# How to digitally sign a document with Smart Card

Tags: java, digital-signature, smartcard, pfx

I just get a project that really out of my expertise which is using Java and Smart Card. I have a smart card and want to use it to authenticate the user digital signature for let say PDF or Doc file. Since the project is on web, I would create a java applet application so I have connection between browser and smart card reader.

I found on internet that I need PKCS#11 drivers, but where can I find it? What is that for?

Comment: @tarzanbappa I actually have searched and found some sample codes out there, but it doesn't meet my requirement or I don't understand how it should be worked. I have changed my question btw.

Comment: Which smart card do you have? Usually sort of middleware (possibly including a PKCS#11 driver) is provided with the card.

Comment: @vlp I'm using Gemalto .NET Card. This card should also be used to logon windows.

Comment: I have no direct experience with .NET cards, but you might have a look at [IDGo 800 middleware](http://www.gemalto.com/products/idgo_800_generic/index.html) which should contain pkcs#11 drivers for some of their .net cards.

Comment: But for windows environment it might be better to use the [Microsoft CryptoAPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_CryptoAPI).

Answer (score 0):

Although I kind of agree with @tarzanbappa above in that your question is not a programming question, let me point you to a quite valuable resource in my opinion: http://www.pwendland.net/IsoApplet/ It's the documentation for an applet that stores the asymmetric keypair, plus a driver so that the applet can be used through OpenSC, which implements PKCS#11.

By reading say documentation, plus the source code, I think you will get lots of insights for your project.